# Can't we create Azure CosmosDB Core(SQL) API account in any regions with Geo-Redundancy, Multi-region Writes and Serverless capacity?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Doesn't Azure support `Geo-Redundancy` and `Multi-region Writes` options for serverless CosmosDB Core(SQL) account? But, those options are listed for Provisioned throughput capacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right, It's a limitation with Serverless Accounts, According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/serverless),

> A serverless account can only run in a single Azure region. It is not
> possible to add additional Azure regions to a serverless account after
> you create it.

There is some work being done in this area, but there is no ETA yet.